# SQL Insert values into table

Tags: sql

I am trying to insert a row into my database table, but I keep on getting a SQL error.

I have a table called tbl_template_log, it has 3 Forgain Keys, user_id, temp_id, savedtemp_id, at the moment I only want to Insert a row with user_id and set temp_id and savedtemp_id to 0.

Query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_template_log (user_id, temp_id, savetemp_id, send_date, send_to, email_send) VALUES (user_id=77, temp_id=0, savetemp_id=0, send_date='2013-10-10', send_to='test@test.com', email_send='hello')
```

Error:

```
    INSERT INTO tbl_template_log (user_id, temp_id, savetemp_id, send_date, send_to, email_send) VALUES (user_id=77, temp_id=0, savetemp_id=0, send_date='2013-10-10', send_to='test@test.com', email_send='hello')
MySQL said: Documentation

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`admin_boltmail`.`tbl_template_log`, CONSTRAINT `tbl_template_log_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`user_id`))
```

From What I understand there is some sort of issue with user_id that the ID of the user has to be existing in tbl_user and ID 77 is an existing user id.....

Could some one point out a mistake I am doing. Thx

Comment: Well I found temporary fix.....All 3 for gain keys have to reference a row in their corresponding tables but Is there a way where I can set temp_id and savedtemp_id to 0.....?

Comment: that's what the constraint does; you could add a dummy row in the corresponding tables with a key of 0, or remove the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a row to this table unless the other tables specified in your foreign key constraints already have a record with the field value you're trying to insert.  That's what a foreign key constraint means.

You're trying to break the rule you defined on your table.  No, the database won't let you break the rule.  You'll either have to add records to the foreign key tables or disable the constraints.